# how to detect Onpress in Push notification React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

I am using `react-native-push-notification` package in my project. when the user clicks a notification. How to Detect it in android and ios using OnNotification Function?? here is the code

```
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";

PushNotification.configure({
    onRegister: function (token) {
      console.log("TOKEN:", token);
    },

    onNotification: function (notification) {
      console.log("[onNotification] :", notification);
 
      notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
    },

    onAction: function (notification) {
      console.log("[onAction]", notification.action);
      console.log("[onAction]:", notification);
    },

    onRegistrationError: function (err) {
      console.error(err.message, err);
    },

    permissions: {
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    },

    popInitialNotification: true,

    requestPermissions: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `userInteraction` property of the `notification` object argument passed to the `onNotification` callback, as mentioned in their [documentation](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#handling-notifications).

Here's an example

```
PushNotification.configure({
  onNotification: function (notification) {
    if (notification.userInteraction) {
      // Handle notification click
    }

    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
  },
});
```

Comment: it works well in Ios but in Android if i press on notification nothing happens.   i.e onNotification: function is not rendering agin in android but in ios when i open notification onNotification returns some objects to handle

Comment: I made few changes in splashactivity.java to trigger onNotification in Android. 
https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1976